# How can I collapse and expand multiple sections with AngularJS and ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

We've been struggling with this problem for a very long time now and we can't find the answer. We 're using Ionic with AngularJS for dynamic views.

We want to click on a item field, in this case a header and make something toggle between visible and invisible.

We have the following code:

```
<ion-item class="item-divider positive" ng-init="toShow=true" ng-click="toShow != toShow">
                Display Header
            </ion-item>
            <div ng-show="toShow">
                <ion-item class="row">
                     <!-- items to show -->
                 </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
```

We can't get this working. We've tried every example on the internet mostly with   examples. We also tried to make functions to the ng-click, but we need it to be dynamic so it can also be used on different fields.

Please help us

Comment: ok i'll ask the obvious - is toShow changing when you click the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have a boolean statement in your ng-click. I'm assuming you wanted `ng-click="toShow = !toShow">`

The second problem is that the `<ion-item>` directive uses an isolate scope, so the toShow variable you are targeting in your ngClick attribute is probably using that isolate scope instead of the parent controller as you might expect. The best way to fix this is to create a setting function to handle the value of toShow, like:

```
$scope.setToShow = function(){
    $scope.toShow = !$scope.toShow;
}
```

now your ngClick becomes

```
ng-click="setToShow()"
```

Angular should look for the function on the controller you'd expect instead of creating a new property on the child scope.

You could also access the $parent directly by using

```
ng-click=$parent.toShow = !$parent.toShow">
```

I wouldn't recommend that, as $parent can end up referencing something else if another scope gets added in a refactor or something.

EDIT: using an array is an easy way to keep track of a list of conditional parameters like you'll need for your example.

```
$scope.setToShow = function(index){
        $scope.toShowArr[index] = $scope.toShow[index] === undefined ? false : !$scope.toShow[index];
}
```

I am handling the undefined condition with false, but you might feel the need to do otherwise.

Comment: I understand your solution is great and it also works, because we already tried this one. The thing is we need to make it dynamic, with this solution we have to make multiple functions for each component we want to expand and collapse. Surely this is not a very effective way.

Comment: Then use an array to keep track of the objects you want to hide/show. You can pass the index of the currently clicked item to the setter function, which in turn handles setting the value at that index in the array. I edited my answer to provide a simple example.

Comment: I want to mark this answer as the answer but we altered the code so it works for our application. We either didn't understand your code properly enough, because each time it gave errors about being undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You don't especially need to set a function in your controller, the only needed thing is to put a `$scope.toShow=false`

Plus, you shouldn't use `ng-init` if you are not in a ng-repeat `loop`
according to Angular's doc:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

So, **in controller:**

```
$scope.toShow=false
```

and **in your template :**

```
<ion-item class="item-divider positive" ng-init="toShow=true" ng-click="toShow = !toShow">
                Display Header
            </ion-item>
            <div ng-show="toShow">
                <ion-item class="row">
                     <!-- items to show -->
                 </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
```

Comment: I changed the condition into an assigment but this doesn't work. When I click the ion-item nothing happens. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I see you edited your post. The thing is, we need it to dynamic as I have stated in my question.

Comment: then you have to make a custom directive `<show-on-click header="{{header}}">{{content}}</show-on-click>`...